# Is there a 'certainty' principle?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, quantum-mechanics, entropy

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle is a restriction on which probability distributions can describe the position and momentum of a quantum particle.

In mathematical terms it says that if $\psi\in L^2$ is normalized, and we define $f,g\in L^1$ by $f(x)=|\psi(x)|^2$ and $g(k)=|\hat\psi(k)|^2$ then we have
$$V(f)V(g)\geq\frac14$$
where $V$ is the variance of the probability distribution with the given density function.

There are various other uncertainty principles, including the [Entropic uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_uncertainty) and [Hardy's uncertainty principle](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/hardys-uncertainty-principle/). Define $f,g\in L^1$ to be *compatible* if there exists $\psi\in L^2$ such that $f(x)=|\psi(x)|^2$ and $g(k)=|\hat{\psi}(k)|^2$. Then each uncertainty principle states a condition which compatible $f$ and $g$ must obey.

I noticed a curious fact, which holds true of everything I could find in the literature calling itself an 'uncertainty principle'. For fixed $f$ the restriction on $g$ is always a *convex* set. For example the set of $g$ satisfying $V(g)\geq\frac1{4V(f)}$ is convex because variance is a concave function on the space of probability distributions.

This does makes sense with the name 'uncertainty principle'. Intuitively, mixing probability distributions cannot produce a result that is more 'certain' than all of them.

However, playing with the Discrete Fourier Transform as a toy model, I noticed that the set of $g$ compatible with a given $f$ need not be convex.

Randomly sampled $g$ compatible with $f = (0.46,0.46,0.08)$ and $f = (0.46,0.46,0.07,0.01)$:

[image: Randomly sampled g compatible with f = (0.46,0.46,0.08) and f = (0.46,0.46,0.07,0.01).]

Note that these sets are nonconvex, and don't even contain the maximally-uncertain uniform distribution (the centre point of the simplex of possible distributions). So the uncertainty of distributions in these sets is bounded above as well as below.

In the case of distributions on $\mathbb R$, can we even find a single $f$ for which we can prove the set of compatible $g$ is not convex?

Is there a 'certainty principle' that, for $f$ within some class, puts an upper bound on the variance or entropy of compatible $g$?

Comment: Sorry but what exactly is the set of $g$ "compatible" with $f$? Thanks.

Comment: That is, I think that given $f$ you obtain a statistic, e.g. $V(f)$, and you want to consider sets like "all $g$ whose Fourier transform has variance $7$". But I'm not sure.

Comment: @usul Define $f,g\in L^1$ to be *compatible* if there exists $\psi\in L^2$ such that $f(x)=|\psi(x)|^2$ for almost all $x$ and $g(k)=|\hat{\psi}(k)|^2$ for almost all $k$. I'll edit the post to make that more explicit, thanks!

Comment: The Paradoxical Certainty Principle: With all certainty, there is no certainty principle.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I would think that someone must know quite a bit this about, given $f$, the structure of the sets of feasible/compatible $\psi$, $\hat{\psi}$, and $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370384/is-there-a-certainty-principle#comment936109_370413), I add a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370384/is-there-a-certainty-principle#comment936069_370413) as an answer with some additional details; but what I meant is really straightforward. The simplest realization is as follows: take any $\psi\in L^2$. Split its support into finitely many parts to obtain a representation $\psi=\sum_{k= 0}^N\psi_k$ where $\psi_0$ is small in $L^2$ (the infinite tail) and $\psi_k$ for $k>0$ are small (less than $\varepsilon$) in $L^1$ (short intervals). Now multiply each $\psi_k$ with $k>0$ by $e^{2\pi i Mkx}$ with $M$ chosen so that $\sup_{\lvert y\rvert>M,1\le k\le N}\lvert\widehat\psi_k(y)\rvert\le \frac{\varepsilon}N$ (it exists by Riemann–Lebesgue). Then the Fourier transform of the resulting function at any point $y$ will be bounded by $\lvert\widehat\psi_0(y)\rvert+3\varepsilon$. The first part doesn't influence anything because its $L^2$-norm is small and the rest is uniformly small and, therefore, spread wide.

If $\psi\in L^1\cap L^2$, then no special treatment of $\psi_0$ is needed. Also, you can get the true uniform smallness by splitting into countably many parts and choosing the phase shifts inductively instead of just using an arithmetic progression. And so on, and so forth.

*Edit:* Now about convexity. Take $f$ to be the characteristic function on $[0,1]$ and consider $g(k)$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ (in this case the point values are continuous functionals). Clearly, every sequence with all zeroes and one $1$ is admissible ($\psi(x)=e^{2\pi ik_0x}$ on $[0,1]$). Thus, if the convexity had held, we would be able to construct a function on $[0,1]$ that is identically $1$ (or, at least, as close to that as we would like) such that $g(0)=g(1)=\frac 12$ and all other $g(k)=0$. However, that would be just a two-term polynomial with equal coefficients, so it would vary quite a bit in absolute value on $[0,1]$. This proves at least that *sometimes* convexity does not hold. I suspect that this trick can be generalized quite a bit but the details are elusive yet.

Comment: The original post included a quote of (I guess) a comment by @OscarCunningham on a comment of yours, both apparently now deleted.  For the benefit of posterity, I inlined this as a description of what was happening, rather than a quote of deleted comment.  I hope that was OK.  (EDIT:  Oops, I see that the comments you were quoting were on [a different answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/370413), not the main post.  Sorry!  Feel free to revert my edit if it was inappropriate.)

Comment: @LSpice Nah, it is fine either way. I'd rather think of the second half of the question now (if I figure it out, I'll edit the post anyway) :-)

Comment: Nice proofs! Took me a while to understand the second one. For fellow novices: The [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) implies that if $\psi$ is supported on $[0,1]$ then $\hat\psi$ is determined by its values on $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I agree it would be nice if we could generalize to more $f$. The compact support looks to me to be essential though.

Comment: @OscarCunningham "The compact support looks to me to be essential" Nope, it isn't. The construction is stable enough: just replace $f$ by anything that is close to the characteristic function of $[0,1]$ in $L^1$ and, instead of specifying the values at points, specify the averages over short intervals around them. So, the convexity fails quite often. My question is rather if it *ever* holds, i.e., if there exists a single $f\in L^1$ with integral $1$ such that the (closure of) the corresponding $g$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

With $D_x=\frac{d}{i dx}$, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in its most classical form can be deduced from the equality
$$
2\Re \langle \hbar D_x u, ix u \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R)}= \langle \bigl[\hbar D_x, ix\bigr] u, u \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\hbar\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2,
$$
which implies
$
\Vert  \hbar D_x u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\Vert  xu\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\ge
 \frac\hbar 2\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2,
$
where the constant $\hbar/2$ can be proven sharp  by testing on a Gaussian function.
So much for the lowerbound. Maybe  a "certainty principle" would mean that we want to deal with the upperbound (?) We have
$$
\Vert  \hbar D_x u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\Vert  xu\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\ge 
\Re \langle \hbar D_x u, ix u \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=
\frac\hbar 2\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2,
$$
but it is true that the left-hand-side could be much larger than the rhs: take for instance
with $\omega$ smooth, valued in $[0,1]$, equal to 1 for $\vert x\vert\ge 2$, to 0 on $\vert x\vert\le 1$, $\lambda \ge 1$,
$$
u_\lambda(x)=(x^2+1)^{-1/2}\omega(x/\lambda),\quad
\Vert u_\lambda\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2 \le π,
$$
$$
u'_\lambda(x)=-\underbrace{x(x^2+1)^{-3/2}\omega(x/\lambda)}_{\text{bounded in $L^2$}}+\underbrace{\frac1\lambda \omega'(x/\lambda) (x^2+1)^{-1/2}}_{\substack{
\text{with limit $0$ in $L^2$}\\\text{since $\omega'$ has support $[\lambda, 2\lambda]$}
}},
$$
$$
x u_\lambda(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \omega(x/\lambda),\quad 
\Vert  xu_\lambda(x)\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}={+\infty}.
$$
As a consequence, the upperbound is $+\infty$.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The fact that there's no bound on $\Vert  \hbar D_x u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}$ in terms of $\Vert  xu\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}$ doesn't mean that we can't bound $\Vert  \hbar D_x u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}$ by some other function of $u$.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Given any $f$ (i.e., $|\psi|$), we can put some "random phase" on it so that the Fourier transform will be uniformly arbitrarily small, which (due to the conservation of the $L^2$ norm), will force it to spread as far as you wish, so no estimate from above on some "concentration quantity" is possible. The convexity question is more interesting one. I would say that the set of $g$ given $f$ is almost never convex, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: @fedja That would certainly answer the second question. But I can't put together the proof from what you wrote. Could you add it as an answer with some additional details?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the von Neumann-Koopman mechanics of interest. Here, classical mechanics is formulated in the same formal language of Diracs transformational theory which superseded both the Wave Mechanics of Schrodinger and the Matrix Mechanics of Heisenberg.

Observables, as in Quantum Mechanics, are represented by self-adjoint operators on the Hilbert space of KvN wave functions. However, unlike quantum mechanics, these operators commute and so are simultaneously measurable. This means that the uncertainty principle of Heisenberg disappears to be replaced by the usual deterministic laws of classical Newtonian mechanics - aka, a 'certainty principle'.